# Installing Ubuntu retaining NTFS drives

Tags: installation, ntfs

I have Windows Vista pre-installed on my laptop. I have 4 NTFS drives (c,d,e,f) on my laptop. I have OS installed on c drive and my data on other drives. Now, I have to switch to Ubuntu completely. So, I want to install Ubuntu on C drive. Is it possible not to touch other drives and access all data from Ubuntu?

P.S.- I am very new to Linux/Ubuntu.Hence, I am sorry if my question sounds weird.

Comment: When booted in Ubuntu cd, u can select which drive you want to install Ubuntu or others. The Ubuntu app will ask you "Do you wan to replace Windows for ubuntu" it will automatically remove and install ubuntu over windows. other option is to manually select your drive format it and install it on that partition.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. No, it is not very advisable.

Linux can read NTFS, however NTFS does not support the Unix-like permissions. This results usually in all files on an NTFS drive having the same exact permissions determined on mount time. This can be deadly for configuration files in the home directory (because, for example, some of them *must* be unreadable for everyone except the user), and is not very convenient in general.

NTFS with Linux is fine as a storage for large media files (music, videos), backups (with Dejadup), but not very suitable for development, and unsuitable for home directories.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you please tell me your best advice?

Comment: My best advice depends on what type of files you keep on the NTFS, why you are switching to Ubuntu and what kind of work you are doing with your workstation.

Comment: Basically, my C drive is nearly 60GB and I am thinking of installing OS there. On other drives, I have some other files like e-books (PDF,CHM,etc), video tutorials, music and other such stuff. I am going to use this machine for development in java/j2ee. The reason of switching to Ubuntu is to learn Ubuntu, Linux. I have been using Windows since long, but I have no knowledge of Ubuntu(read Linux).

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest duel booting because I think many of your Windows specific files will become unusable , like the CHM/help files would require a Windows emulator to use (I believe). I recently used the Windows installer http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer and it was as painless as drinking a beer.

Use Windows to download and run it, and it asks you how much of which drive you want to use. I used 9GB of my C: drive, and after installing everything I want still have 6GB free.

Afterwards, on reboot you get to choose which OS you want to use. I also went back into Windows and found where to set Ubuntu as the default OS, so it only launches Windows if I tell it to, like if I need to view a CHM file ;)